# for loop is not iterating correctly

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop, append

I tried to iterate through this list and append the indexes of the parenthases, but it gave the wrong ones back.

Code:

```
t = "(= 2 (+ 4 5))"
a = []
for each in t:
        if (each == '(') or (each == ')'):
            a.append(t.index(each))
        else:
            pass
print(t)
print(a)
```

Result:

```
(= 2 (+ 4 5))
[0, 0, 11, 11]
```

It should be:

```
(= 2 (+ 4 5))
[0, 5, 11, 12]
```

Comment: `list.index()`will always return the index of first occurrence

Comment: Instead of a foreach loop, just use a for loop to track the index that you're currently looking at.

Comment: `a = [idx for idx, ch in enumerate(t) if ch in '()']`

Comment: The `for` loop is iterating fine, as evidenced by the fact that *something* was added to `a` for each `(` and `)` in `t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid making python search back through a list (You have `t.index(each)`) by using `enumerate()` to get the index directly:

```py
t = "(= 2 (+ 4 5))"
a = []
for index,each in enumerate(t):
        if (each == '(') or (each == ')'):
            a.append(index)
        else:
            pass
print(t)
print(a)
```

Output as requested